# Super CSV Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, csv, supercsv

I am planning to use [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) after looking at all pros and cons of different CSV APIs available in Java.

Can any one post an updated Maven repository with latest version (2.0.1 Final I believe)
I am still seeing beta version in Maven repo.

Comment: [According to the project's homepage](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) the latest version is 2.0.0. [According to the repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/?source=navbar) the current developer version is a 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Snapshots are not deployed to the central Maven repository as far as I know. You should build it yourself if you can't wait for it to be released.

Comment: Yes, we use Sonatype's [OSS repository](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) so if we deploy snapshots they will only be there - whereas release versions get synched to Maven Central. Version 2.0.1 will be out soon - watch our [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/) to keep up to date. The version you see on the project website and on SourceForge is the latest released version (and will be in the Maven Central repo). 2.0.1 is still a SNAPSHOT (in Subversion) because it hasn't been released yet

Comment: I've just released 2.0.1 - it should be synched to Maven central in a few hours :)

Comment: @HoundDog what's the difference between super-csv-dozer and super-csv?

Comment: @NitinGurram As detailed on the [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/downloading.html), super-csv-dozer is the [Dozer extension](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/dozer.html). It contains a reader and writer which support deep-mapping and index-based mapping (which the readers/writers in the standard super-csv artifact don't support). It's very new, so if you have any feedback on it please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version is 2.0.0 (see the [official site](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/downloading.html)). So you can easily get it from the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7CSuperCSV).